# gt package how to format column summary rows : how to format summary values with numbers AND percent based on columns

Tags: r, gt

I have a frequency and relative frequency table.

```
jobs <- c("teacher", "teacher", "teacher", "teacher", "researcher", "researcher" , "researcher" , "researcher", "barman", "barman" )

jobs <- data.frame(jobs)
```

I want to format my summary row with numbers for n and  with percent for my freq column :

1. What I tried: all values are in percent :

   ```
   jobs %>%
    count(jobs) %>%
    mutate(frequence = n/sum(n))  %>%
    gt(rowname_col =  "jobs")  %>%  
    grand_summary_rows (
      columns = vars(n, frequence),
      fns = list(Total =~sum(.)),
      formatter = fmt_percent
     )
   ```
2. What I tried: retourns me an error

   ```
   jobs %>%
     count(jobs) %>%
     mutate(frequence = n/sum(n))  %>%
     gt(rowname_col =  "jobs")  %>%  
     grand_summary_rows (
      columns = vars(n, frequence),
      fns = list(Total =~sum(.)),
      formatter = fmt_percent(columns = "frequence"),
      formatter = fmt_number(columns = "n")
     )
   ```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use different formatting for each of the summary rows, you can use two calls to `grand_summary_rows`, one for each column with different formatting specified.

```
jobs <- c("teacher", "teacher", "teacher", "teacher", "researcher", 
          "researcher" , "researcher" , "researcher", "barman", "barman" )
jobs <- data.frame(jobs)

jobs %>%
  count(jobs) %>%
  mutate(frequence = n/sum(n))  %>%
  gt(rowname_col =  "jobs")  %>%  
  grand_summary_rows (
    columns = "n",
    fns = list(Total =~sum(.)),
    formatter = fmt_number
  ) %>%
  grand_summary_rows (
    columns = "frequence",
    fns = list(Total =~sum(.)),
    formatter = fmt_percent
  )
```

[image: Table with numeric and percent summary rows]

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem stumped me for a little while: data.frames take each vector as a *named* parameter

```
jobs_vector <- c("teacher", "teacher", "teacher", "teacher", "researcher", "researcher" , "researcher" , "researcher", "barman", "barman")
df <- data.frame(jobs = jobs_vector)
```

Your next problem is solved with the `tabyl()` function from the `janitor` package.

```
library(janitor)
tabyl(df, jobs)
```

Returns

[image]

To get a publication-quality table, you are right to use the `gt` package.
Here are two `gt`'s useful functions:

```
library(gt)
df1 %>% 
  gt(rowname_col = jobs) %>% 
  opt_row_striping() %>% 
  gtsave("myTable.png")
```

[image]